# Erlang port doesn't process C++/Qt reply correctly

Tags: c++, qt, erlang, stdin, erlang-ports

I am trying to communicate an Erlang program with a simple Qt window app through an Erlang port.

The problem is that the result from the Qt window event (`on_pushButton_clicked()`) shows up in Erlang port only after the window is closed and not when the button is pressed:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "choosefileform.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    fprintf(stdout, "window_input:");
    printf(ui->lineEdit->text().toAscii());
printf("~n");


    ChooseFileForm* fn  = new ChooseFileForm();

    this->close();
    fn->show();
}
```

Erlang (sending a Message just does nothing here, we are interested in getting data from Qt):

```
connect(Message) ->
    Cmd = "./myqtwindowapp \n",
    Port = open_port({spawn,Cmd}, [stream,use_stdio,exit_status]),
    Payload = string:concat(Message, "\n"),
    erlang:port_command(Port, Payload),
    receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            ?DBG("Received data: ~p~n", [Data]),
        Other ->
            io:format("Unexpected data: ~p~n", [Other])
    after 15000 ->
            ?DBG("Received nothing~n", [])
    end.
```

The result of running this and filling the text field in the window is nothing (Erlang gets nothing and just waits in the `receive` clause):

Only when I manually close the window Erlang says:

```
Received data: "window_input:hello"
```

So, why don't I get data from Qt into Erlang port immediately?

**UPD. Solution:**

The solution was to flush() the Qt's buffer:

instead of `fprintf(stdout, "window_input:");` I used

```
cin >> c;
cout << c;
cout.flush();
```

And it worked.

P.S. However, I do not understand why this problem did not happen with testing the same Qt app in console - it returned data immediately I filled in the text field in the window (i.e. on event).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not so much experienced with C++ but seems you don't flush data from your port. (And also `"~n"` is not new line in C++ which is not case because you use `stream` mode instead `line`.)

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly flush the data.

Comment: Thanks Hynek and rvirding! But how can I do that? I have not found anything of explicitly flushing the port in its official documentation.

Comment: @MartinLee: No, you don't need flush _port_ you have to flush output in your stdout io handle i.e. call `fflush(stdout)` after your message  in `MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked` function.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: So, my UPD Solution is correct, right?